# Oracle Linux virtual machine's root size is not getting increased

Tags: hard-drive, root, gparted

Size of root was 100% in OEL 7 virtual machine in ESXi, so I have used Gpated iso to resize the root space. After booting OEL 7 `df -h` still showing as 100% used i.e. still showing old size.

Comment: Yes, only volume size was increased. Now I have used ```lvextend``` and ```xfs_growfs```. Now it is fine. Thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you only increase the partition/volume size? If so, you will also need to use your filesystem's tools to expand the filesystem into the new space.